How to Implement a Memory-Efficient Custom Iterator for Large Files in Python?
I need to iterate over extremely large files (several gigabytes each) in Python without loading the entire file into memory. Specifically, I want to implement a custom iterator that reads and processes data from these large files efficiently. What are the best practices and techniques for achieving this?
I have experimented with Python’s fileinput module and streaming libraries, but I’m unsure of the best approach to implement a memory-efficient iterator for large files
Can someone provide a comprehensive example or explanation of how to implement a memory-efficient custom iterator in Python for reading and processing large files? I am particularly interested in techniques that optimize memory usage and maintain high performance.

While i have 0 experience on exact question you are asking, im quite sure the file type and its contents is quite relevant factor here.

Not sure if that fits your corporate expectations, but the built-in function open returns a pretty good iterator.

Why does it need to be custom? What's wrong with using one that already exists for the file format? I'd say that's the best practice.

The way you do this will depend on the structure and type of your data. Unfortunately you've chosen not to share that critical piece of information

@JohnnyCheesecutter Agreed if the file is line-oriented text but it may not be suitable for this particular use-case
